# Legacy Active Server Pages and IE10 Emulation

Tags: internet-explorer

How does one set a Classic ASP web application to use Browser Mode IE10 and Document Mode “IE5 quirks” when the browser used is IE 10?

Note:

- The solution can not use the server HTTP Response Header setting for all applications
- So far we have tried variations of the following:

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=5" >
```

The only way I can get IE5 quirks mode is by using the compatibility view icon offered by IE10. After clicking I noticed IE10 could remember your choice and place the url in the compatible view settings list so that your code change is not the final result unless you clear the check list and appropriate check boxes.

So, IE10 is able to get itself to render in IE10 Compat View, and Document Mode: IE5 quirks, but I have yet to get a meta tag to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION
I solved the problem by providing a meta tag within an “include” file that contains HTML markup. 
Code the followign into the Head tag, but before any script. 
Please_wait_top.asp page:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=5">
</head>
```

COPA_view_agreements.asp

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=5">

  <title>
    We are here
    </title>

  </head>
```

Please see screen shots.
Note: Per MS 
“You have to include that metadata before running scripts or rendering HTML. The mode can be switched only before you’ve done any work which uses a rendering and scripting engine, otherwise we decide based on the header or the group policy.”
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2012/02/29/using-x-ua-compatible-to-create-durable-enterprise-web-applications.aspx 
[image]